# What is wrong with my Simulink model of an active suspension system?

Tags: matlab, controls, simulation, simulink, simscape

I am new to Simulink and am trying to make a simulation of an active vehicle suspension with Simscape. For some reason, I am getting unreasonable results in my sim, despite following the examples on the mathworks website pretty closely. I have temporarily disabled the acceleration command for testing.

The input from the signal builder is a sinusoidal function. I don't understand why the values of the suspension motion for the top mass are higher than the input.

[image: enter link description here]

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if this is the only issue, but I'd strongly recommend not using that Derivative block. The derivative you get there is a numerical approximation that is highly depending on the time step the solver takes. It can cause instability.

If you want the acceleration as a direct measurement, I would instead recommend grabbing an Ideal Force Sensor block, connecting it in series with the Mass block, and then dividing by the mass to get acceleration.